# Trying to remove a Element from a DefaultListModel object

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, listmodel

using java version 9
I have some test code to remove a item from a list created by passing a refrence to  by DefaultListModel.
This is what I do.

1. create a DefaultListModel object
2. add 8 elements to it (A..H) by calling addElement
3. remove a item by calling removeElement
4. create a Jlist pass a reference of my DefaultListModel to it
5. The list box displays all 8 items, nothing got removed.
   code

   ```
    philosophers = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    philosophers.addElement( "A" );
    philosophers.addElement( "B" );
    philosophers.addElement( "C" );
    philosophers.addElement( "D" );
    philosophers.addElement( "E" );
    philosophers.addElement( "F" );
    philosophers.addElement( "G" );
    philosophers.addElement( "H" );
    philosophers.removeElement(1);
    lista = new JList<String>( philosophers );
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you have an issue, hit the JavaDocs...

[`DefaultListModel#removeElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElement-java.lang.Object-)

> ```
> public boolean removeElement(Object obj)
> ```
>
> Removes the
>
> first (lowest-indexed) occurrence of the argument from this list.
> **Parameters:**
>  obj - the component to be removed

The interesting point here is, the parameter is an `Object`, not a index.  This means, with Java's auto-boxing, you're actually trying to remove a `Integer(1)`, which does't exist in the model.

Instead, if you did something like `philosophers.removeElement("B");`, you might have had more luck.

However, if we read a little more into the JavaDocs we find

[`DefaultListModel#remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#remove-int-)

> ```
> public E remove(int index)
> ```
>
> Removes the element at the
>
> specified position in this list. Returns the element that was removed
> from the list.
>  Throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the
> index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).
>
> **Parameters:**
>  index - the index of the element to removed

Ah, that sounds more like what you're after